# How would you go about applying curvature to the rendering of a flat surface?

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, planet

I want to draw a 2D planet surface. I have a set of tiles, which by themselves are flat if you draw them. Now I want to apply something to the drawing process, which makes it look curved the more you go to the edges of the screen [(kind of like this)](https://img.itch.io/aW1hZ2UvODI3NDYvMzg5NTE2LmdpZg==/original/oIvYGr.gif). Does anyone have an idea how you could do that?

If its relevant, Im using the LibGDX framework for Java.

Comment: You posted this exact same question a couple of hours ago.

Comment: @Dispersia No, my initial question was about turning a flat surface into a circle, this is just about applying some curvature.